# How to programmatically add rows to DataGrid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So as the title states, I'm trying to add rows to a DataGrid programmatically using C# but I can't seem to make it work. This is what I have so far.

```
// I have a DataGrid declared as dg in the XAML

foreach (string s in array) {
    int index = 0;
    DataGridRow dgRow = new DataGridRow();
    foreach (DataGridColumn dgColumn in columns)
    {
        // Trying to add Text to dgRow here but IDK how
        index++;
    }
}
```

I've been googling around and the closest I got to adding anything was to use `{column = value}` but it just throws me an error. Really out of ideas now though :\

Comment: Best way to use DataGridView to bound it with a DataSource(Datatable,dataset etc) and make changes in the datasource itself. Also in your code, you have to add **dgRow** in your datagridview to it be visible in UI.

Comment: How do I "bind" it to a DataTable exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's you can do it better way by binding a source to datagridview

```
        // Creating DataSource here as datatable having two columns
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        // Adding the rows in datatable
        for (int iCount = 1; iCount < 6; iCount++)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = iCount;
            row["Name"] = "Name " + iCount;
            dt.Rows.AddRow(row);
        }

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        // Set AutoGenerateColumns true to generate columns as per datasource.
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        // Finally bind the datasource to datagridview.
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

In Case you are using WPF DataGrid
you can bind it like this way-

```
dgv.DataContext = employeeData.DefaultView;
```

and in

> XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dgv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Hi Rohit! Is there any way to get this to work with `DataGrid`? DataGridView doesn't seem to be available in my build of C#(?)

Comment: Hi, Rohit, I just realized DataGridView isn't available in WPF. I'm using WPF. Is there a way to make this work with WPF?

Comment: No it doesn't. I just tried and it refuses to even compile :\

Comment: As it turns out, all I was missing from making your code work was the ` ItemsSource="{Binding}"`hahaha :| THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been going crazy over this for a while now

Comment: glad that it helped you out. . .. .

Comment: don't you need to add the row? NewRow does not add by default, MSDN says: row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = i; table.Rows.Add(row); Also you shouldn't bind it to ItemSource?

Answer (score 2):

```
//create datatable and columns,
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 1"));
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 2"));

//simple way create object for rowvalues here i have given only 2 add as per your requirement
object[] RowValues = { "", "" };

//assign values into row object
RowValues[0] = "your value 1";
RowValues[1] = "your value 2";

//create new data row
DataRow dRow;
dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues);
dtable.AcceptChanges();

//now bind datatable to gridview... 
gridview.datasource=dbtable;
gridview.databind();
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

did you try?:

```
int n=5; // number of rows you want to add
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(n);

// you can add (names of the rows) if you have them in your array
//for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
//dataGridView1[0, i].Value = array[i];
```